# Lenovo IdeaPad 700-17ISK beeps every 2 minutes

Tags: windows-10, laptop, lenovo-laptop, system-sounds

I bought [Lenovo IdeaPad 700-17ISK](https://www.computeruniverse.ru/en/products/90674438/lenovo-ideapad-700-17isk-80rv008qge.asp).

After 2 weeks, laptop started to beep one time every 1-2 min. A Beep comes from the right side.

It is important that Windows sound comes from the left side. This is another source of noise.

The Beep occurs when the computer is turned on and when the computer is turned off.

Sound occurs within a few months. In general, the computer works correctly.

What is it?

The beep is http://vocaroo.com/i/s0HzEgREfnVR

Comment: Does the beep every 1-2 minutes happen only when the power adapter is plugged in? Can you reproduce the same beep by plugging and unplugging the power adapter?

Comment: @DrZoo I tried to unplug the power adapter. Beeps is continue.

Comment: Hmmm I was hoping it was related to the weird power beep setting that some Lenovo's have. The power beep occurs when the power adapter starts and stops. You could try going into the BIOS to see if you have the power beep option and turn it off. It may or may not solve the issue, but it's probably worth a shot.

Comment: @DrZoo My bios power beep option were disable.